# php "foreach" scan image directory folders, retrieve large and thumb (use for image gallery)

Tags: php, foreach, get, scandir

Head is smoking, i tried several solutions getting the subdirectories in an array like

```
$myDir = '/images/'; // 
foreach ( $myDirArray = array_filter(glob($myDir . '*'), 'is_dir') as $DirName ) {
etc..
```

I am using a php script to get large images out of a specific folder, retrieve their thumb from  "thumbs" folder. Script generates automatically a thumb if non exists (function make_thumb)
Works like a charm for a single images folder, but need your help for a generic solution in PHP, to scan parent directory and folders inside and keep the make_thumb function

My code:
Set the image/thumb directory

```
    $images_dir = 'Nature/';
    $thumbs_dir = 'Nature/thumbs/';
    $thumbs_size = 120;
```

Get file extension:

```
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
  return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}
```

Get the files

```
    function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg')) {
      $files = array();
      if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
          if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
            $files[] = $file;
          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      }
      return $files;
    }
```

Generate the gallery (and extract captions for further use)

```
    $image_files = get_files($images_dir);
    if(count($image_files)) {
      $index = 0;
      foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
        $index++;
        $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
        $filename = $file; 
        $caption = preg_replace(array('/^.+--/', '/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$/', '/_/'), array('','',' '), $filename); //Extracting the caption
        if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
          $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
          if($extension) {
            make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_size);
          }
        }
        echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" title="',$caption,'"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
      }
    }
    else {
      echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
    }
```

Comment: So what happened when you tried using the `foreach` loop at the start of the question? Are you logging errors? Also of note, PHP has some more modern methods for dealing with listing filesystems: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: My problem was, that i could not manage to find a proper way to loop trough the folders to grap their files $images_files = get_files.